# Does Azure App Service for Linux with Multi-Containers allow multiple yaml files?

Tags: azure, docker, docker-compose, azure-web-app-service

I'm experimenting with Azure App Service for Linux + Multi-Container apps (aka Docker-Compose).

On my localhost development machine I have:

- `docker-compose.yml` (main file)
- `docker-compose.override.yml` (localhost dev settings, via environment vars)
- `docker-compose.development.yml` (azure development experiment settings via environment vars)

the main `docker-compose.yml` file has about 8 images in it, from a reverse-proxy to some web sites and then some background hosts that do background work.

All work 100% awesome on my localhost.

Now, I'm trying to see if this can get put up to azure with the new Azure App Service for Linux + Multi-Containers. This is part of the UI:

[image]

It's only allowing me 1x yaml file to use as the configuration. So I have no idea how to *also* add my `docker-compose.development.yml` file as a second file which will override any existing settinsg from the main file.

Similar if I do `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml docker-compose.development.yml up`

Is this possible with Azure App Service for Linux + Multi-Containers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the Azure App Service for Linux + Multi-Container apps do not support multiple yaml files, just one for this moment, basically it is encoding that file and pass it through linux_fx_version, you can see the same process using Azure CLI, see the code [here](https://nam06.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2FAzure%2Fazure-cli%2Fblob%2F6be86c144e37214e2fbe2d25aec3bd10bfd61bf6%2Fsrc%2Fazure-cli%2Fazure%2Fcli%2Fcommand_modules%2Fappservice%2Fcustom.py%23L943&data=02%7C01%7Cv-chaxu%40microsoft.com%7Ce96c3b53637b4034fcb908d70bf0aff5%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C636991000707382992&sdata=vz3w0zzSF%2BCyHUx%2FkkkzEURdxBtmCqd1bfM2%2B6D8a4E%3D&reserved=0). And also there are just a few supported options, check the support options list in [Docker Compose Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/configure-custom-container#docker-compose-options).

Comment: I was able to work around this by explicitly merging my override files locally before uploading the merged Compose config to Azure.

For example:

    `docker run --rm -v ${PWD}:/workdir mikefarah/yq sh -c "yq merge docker-compose.yml docker-compose.development.yml > docker-compose.merge.yml"`

The above command will create a file named `docker-compose.merge.yml`, which _should_ be equivalent to specifying the `-f` override flags.

Comment: @naitsirhc Unfortunately, Azure Web App does not support to customize the docker command currently.

Comment: I apologize if I was not clear in my original comment. The command in my post above is intended to run _locally_, resulting in a _single_ Docker Compose YAML configuration that can be uploaded to the "Container settings" section of the corresponding Azure Web App Service multi-container instance in the Azure portal. I can confirm that this is working, as I am already using this approach with several Web App Service instances.